# Is there a way to have valgrind spit out a message everytime I allocate memory

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind, memory-leak-detector

I am working a on a large C project and just introduced what I believe is a memory leak of a sort. As I run the code my RAM gets eaten up very fast and then frees up when I exit my program. The thing is valgrind doesn't seem to think there is a memory leak and doesn't spit out any messages.

I am running it with

```
./valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes ./a.out
```

My guess is that I am building up some large dynamic list and then freeing at the end, so valgrind doesn't detect it. Is there some way to have valgrind spit out a message every time a function dynamically allocates memory so I can see what function is being called that builds up the memory.

Or is there some other program that give me detailed memory data of what functions have dynamically allocated how much memory?

Comment: First of all, what is your program doing? Does it create large trees or lists or other dynamically created data-structures? If not, do you have memory allocations in one or more loops? And that Valgrind doesn't report a leak, means you're keeping track of all your allocations, and freeing them on exit. Which basically means your program is just creating a lot of data. If that data is really needed or not is impossible for us to say.

Comment: I am doing all of the above, mostly lists. I am not asking you if my data is needed or not, I am still trying to identify where the buildup of data is coming from. I am asking how I can ascertain this information with valgrind, or some other program.

Comment: IMO, that information will probably be pretty useless. It will likely show your one function where you do all your allocations, with the same callstack every time. I think it would be better and more productive if you took a closer look at the data itself, and ask yourself if you really need all the data you create for the full life-time of the program.

Comment: The program is a game engine wit ha lot of different use cases and the callstack is constantly changing depending on user actions. I dont really need your specific opinion, I am looking for someone who knows the ins and outs of valgrind and or has another suggestion for a program that can give me detailed information on my memory usage.

Comment: You could comment out the code that frees the memory for testing, then valgrind will report everything.

Comment: Valgrind aside, you could "mock" malloc and replace it with a macro that spits out a logging diagnostic before calling the real malloc. Something like `#define malloc(n) (log(#n " bytes allocated", __func__, __FILE__, #__LINE__), malloc(n))`. Then same with free (and maybe calloc + realloc etc).

Comment: _Is there some other program that give me detailed memory data of what functions have dynamically allocated how much memory?_

For exactly same task I used [heap-profiling using tcmalloc](https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/heapprofile.html). Hope this helps.